# insmod: cannot insert './intrpt.ko': Function not implemented

Tags: linux, kernel, embedded

I'm writing a kernel module that receives interrupts for mpc8308 (PowerPC) board. when I make the code for Ubuntu and my current version of kernel it works well with interrupt of keyboard, but when I Cross build it for mpc8308 board (2.6.29.6 kernel) and I want to load it into kernel with `insmod` command I get error:

```
insmod: cannot insert './intrpt.ko': Function not implemented
```

my code is:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>

#define DRIVER_AUTHOR "AVM"
#define DRIVER_DESC "A sample driver"

static irqreturn_t irq_handler(int irq, void *dev_id, struct pt_regs *regs)
{
  printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello Interrupt world.\n");
  return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
/*
* Initialize the module − register the IRQ handler
*/
int init_module()
{
  free_irq(1, NULL);
  return request_irq(1, irq_handler, IRQF_SHARED, "test_keyboard_irq_handler",
                    (void *)(irq_handler));
}
/*
* Cleanup
*/
void cleanup_module()
{
  free_irq(1, NULL);
}

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR(DRIVER_AUTHOR);
MODULE_DESCRIPTION(DRIVER_DESC);
MODULE_SUPPORTED_DEVICE("testdevice");
```

and output of `modinfo ./intrpt.ko` is:

```
filename:       ./intrpt.ko
description:    A sample driver
author:          
license:        GPL
depends:        
vermagic:       2.6.29.6-rt23 mod_unload
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem while inserting module into the kernel. Enter your current kernel version correctly go to cd /lib/modules/your-kernel-version-gereric/ directory and check whether build directory is present or not. If present then you can directly compile your module using below command

```
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD)
```